# How to use Buddypress xProfile field as Wordpress Bio

Tags: author, user-meta, buddypress

First time using this forum. I need some serious help with this question. I am trying to display a user's bio without using the backend. Reason being, I do not allow my users to go through the backend of my website for any reason. So this being said, they cannot create a wordpress bio, which in turn stops them from having a bio be displayed on author boxes under posts.

I have asked everywhere, and no one can help me. I have heard it was possible to create a Buddypress profile field with xProfile, and then code it to be displayed as the warpers bio, which would have it appear in author boxes. Sadly, I do not know how to do this. Can someone please assist me in this, or give me some other kind of answer? Maybe UserMeta?

For discussions sake, let's say the name of the profile field would be "Bio". Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately third party plugins are off-topic in WPSE. You may try buddypress forums, where you can find threads like [this one](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/display-a-value-of-a-particular-custom-profile-field/) which can be helpful for your question.

Comment: Much appreciated! I thank you for telling me all this. Like I said, I am new here so I am not sure what goes on. Still trying to figure out this issue. Couldn't hack it with the great link you gave me. @cybmeta

Answer (score 1):

To just answer this question.. Hope it's okay to pull this back up ^^

```
        <div class="profile-bio">
            <!-- Profile user info bio text -->
            <?php 
                if ( $string = xprofile_get_field_data( 'About', get_the_author_meta('ID') ) ) {
                    echo '<div class="author-about">';
                    echo    $string;
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            ?><!-- EOF Profile user info bio text -->
        </div>
```

I'm also using [this](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-xprofile-custom-fields-type/), but you can use this for all fields.